# Navbar brand image not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to get a nabber brand image to be displayed. Working fine across Chrome/Safari/IE but not in FF. When the user scrolls up, the brand image grows.

http://sam-stone.co.uk/sam/

I have tried making the image static but that does not show either. Any ideas?

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin-top: -75px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
}
.shrink .navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
$('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
}
else {
$('.navbar').removeClass('shrink'); }
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top normal" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logoCircle.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-top-right">
        <li>
        <form action="demo_form.asp">
        <input type="text" class="form-control empty" id="iconified" placeholder="&#xF002; Search Blog" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome">
<br>
        </form>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src = "images/sample.png"> Samples (0 Samples)</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li> 
        <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">SHOWCASE</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li> 
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: please paste your javascript/css for that element

Comment: It's your filter: url("#drop-shadow"); causing the error in firefox

Comment: @cport1 thanks. All sorted. Serves me right for c&p'ing that code.